# Fullcalendar ui-calendar configuration not being read

Tags: angularjs, fullcalendar

I'm starting to use fullcalendar ui-calendar (the angular version).

```
    var app = angular.module('MyApp', ['ui.calendar'])
    .controller('MainController', function ($scope) {

    var events = [
        { title: "event1", start: new Date(2015, 6, 21) },
        { title: "event2", start: new Date(2015, 7, 31), end: new Date(2015, 8, 02) },
        { title: "event3", start: new Date(2015, 8, 01) },
    ];

    $scope.eventSources = [events];

    $scope.calOptions = {

        editable: true,
        header: {
            left: 'prev',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'next'
        }
    };
});


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<link href="Scripts/fullcalendar-2.3.2/fullcalendar.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/moment.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/fullcalendar-2.3.2/fullcalendar.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/calendar.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
<title></title>
```

```
<div ng-controller="MainController">

    <div class="calendar" ui-calendar="calOptions" ng-model="eventSources"></div>

</div>
```

The problem is that the configuration is ignored. the events did get in...
Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made [a plunker with your code](http://plnkr.co/edit/LM39yL?p=preview) and it's working properly.

Check that you get your config properly at the directive, when it load the config:

```
this.getFullCalendarConfig = function(calendarSettings, uiCalendarConfig){
          var config = {};

          angular.extend(config, uiCalendarConfig);
          angular.extend(config, calendarSettings);

          angular.forEach(config, function(value,key){
            if (typeof value === 'function'){
              config[key] = wrapFunctionWithScopeApply(config[key]);
            }
          });

          return config;
      };
```

Comment: What It was? Consider sharing it, maybe it will help somebody

Comment: I'm having the same issue, how did you fix it @GuyZ?

Comment: Found the solution! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31896463/cant-pass-fullcalendar-options-through-the-directive-in-angularjs/31897301#31897301