# Can't pass Fullcalendar options through the directive in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, fullcalendar, angular-ui

I trying to implement a simple example with AngularJS Fullcalendar direcive from here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-calendar

It doesn't display any event neither apply custom FullCalendar settings and no error are shown, what am I doing wrong?

And my code is following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="foodViewApp">
<head lang="en">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>AngularJS Tutorial</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/index.css">
<!-- fullcalendar -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/fullcalendar.css">


<script src="resources/lib/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="resources/lib/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="resources/lib/momentjs/moment-with-locales.js"></script>

<script src="resources/lib/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.4/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.4/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="resources/lib/fullcalendar/calendar.js"></script>
<script src="resources/lib/humanize-duration/humanize-duration.js"></script>
<script src="resources/lib/angular-timer/angular-timer.min.js"></script>
<script src="resources/lib/fullcalendar/gcal.js"></script>



<!-- App libs  -->
    <script src="resources/js/app/app.js"></script>
    <script src="resources/js/app/controllers/controllers.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MainController">



    <!-- HEADER AND NAVBAR -->
        <header>
            <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Scheduler</a>
                    </div>

                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" ng-hide="isActive('/display')">

                        <li><a href="#schedule"><i class="fa fa-shield"></i> Schedule</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </header>

        <!-- MAIN CONTENT AND INJECTED VIEWS -->
        <div id="main">
            <div data-ng-view=""></div>
        </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Application with routing:

```
var app = angular.module('foodViewApp',['ngRoute','timer','ui.calendar']);

app.config(function ($routeProvider){
    console.log("test");
    $routeProvider

        .when('/schedule',{
            controller:     'ScheduleController',
            templateUrl:    'schedule.html'
        })

        .otherwise({
            redirectTo:     '/schedule'
        });
});
```

controllers.js:

```
    app.controller('MainController', function($scope, $location, categoryFactory){

    $scope.isActive = function(viewLocation) {
        return viewLocation === $location.path();
    };


    $scope.title = $location.path();
});
app.controller('ScheduleController', function($scope) {
    /* config object */
    $scope.uiConfig = {
      calendar:{
        height: 450,
        editable: true,
        header:{
          left: 'month basicWeek basicDay agendaWeek agendaDay',
          center: 'title',
          right: 'today prev,next'
        },
        dayClick: $scope.alertEventOnClick,
        eventDrop: $scope.alertOnDrop,
        eventResize: $scope.alertOnResize
      }
    };

    var date = new Date();
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = date.getMonth();
    var y = date.getFullYear();

    /* event source that contains custom events on the scope */
    $scope.eventSources = [
      {title: 'All Day Event',start: new Date(y, m, 1)},
      {title: 'Long Event',start: new Date(y, m, d - 5),end: new Date(y, m, d - 2)},
      {id: 999,title: 'Repeating Event',start: new Date(y, m, d - 3, 16, 0),allDay: false},
      {id: 999,title: 'Repeating Event',start: new Date(y, m, d + 4, 16, 0),allDay: false},
      {title: 'Birthday Party',start: new Date(y, m, d + 1, 19, 0),end: new Date(y, m, d + 1, 22, 30),allDay: false}
    ];
});
```

schedule.html (view)

```
<div class="container">
    <div ui-calendar="uiConfig.calendar" ng-model="eventSources"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it's bug according to:
this: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-calendar/issues/303
and this: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-calendar/issues/297
it affects FullCalendar directive v1.0.0 according to links above and to solve it your should replace

```
ui-calendar="uiConfig.calendar"
```

with

```
ui-calendar="{{uiConfig.calendar}}"
```

**UPDATE**: 
It looks that latest version of this directive which available through the bower is fixed already.